# Pantone Color Picker

Tags: jquery, color-picker

I'd like to use a color picker on my web site similar to http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/#about, but which only allows the choice from set Pantone colors (instead of all RGB / HEX colors).  Does anyone know if this exists? It looks like something like the "Really Simple Color Picker" at http://laktek.com/2008/10/27/really-simple-color-picker-in-jquery/ could be used, but I'd prefer not to have to code in all the pantone colors if it has already been done.

Comment: I don't think you're going to find an existing product anywhere except from PANTONE itself, since they own the rights to the color palette -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pantone#Intellectual_property

Comment: Ah, I did not realize that.  I'll have to look into it the IP question more as I do need I do need Pantone choices. Also, it looks like PANTONE has mobile products but no widgets for web pages.  Thanks for the help though.